# SharePoint 2013 custom search connector fails after patch

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, bdc, bdc-model, custom-bdc

We have a custom search connector that we built to make documents from another system searchable from SharePoint. This worked fine for a year until we decided to add a CU(October 2015 uber).

The connector still works fine when crawling folders but fails when it comes to files with this error in ULS:

> CRobot Thread::Thread failed to move BDC blob file for docID XXXXX :file name chunk is corrupted Index is not number

I've searched everywhere for an answer. I've even set up a new development server from scratch with this patch applied and the error occurs there as well.

Any ideas what is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Robert, 
cause for this:
When you execute a full crawl for a binary large objects (BDC) content source that contains email messages that have attachments, you receive the following error message:
CRobotThread::Thread failed to move BDC blob file.

---

this is fixed by (Cumulative update package for SharePoint Foundation 2013 (SharePoint Foundation server-package): May 7, 2014) however after installing September 2015 Uber pack you can observe this issue.

Take a look below:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2015/09/17/uber-packages-for-september-2015-cu-for-sharepoint-2013-have-been-released/

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2015/07/15/important-psconfig-is-mandatory-for-july-2015-cu-for-sharepoint-2013/

I will update late.